# How can I execute a function during the count-down timer?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, countdown

I want to collect some real-time values during a time period and then proceed accordingly. Below is the code of java android studio. However, I cannot find any way to execute a function during the count-down timer in dart.

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            sum = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.values[0], 2)
                    + Math.pow(event.values[1], 2)
                    + Math.pow(event.values[2], 2)));
            repeat_count++;
            Log.e("Check sum", String.valueOf(sum));
            if ((sum >= 9.80) && (sum <= 11.0)) {
                count++;
            }

        }


        public void onFinish() {
            String c = String.valueOf(count);
            String rep=String.valueOf(repeat_count);
            Log.e("Count is", c);
            Log.e("Loop count",rep);
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("count_value",count);
            setResult(2, intent);
            finish();


        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot find any way to execute a function during the count-down timer in dart.

It's not very clear what you're asking.  Dart doesn't have a `CountDownTimer` class if that's what you mean, but you could implement one yourself without much trouble.  You mostly just need to use [`Timer.periodic`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) to invoke a callback at regular intervals and then to cancel that `Timer` after a sufficient total amount of time has elapsed.

An implementation that is more similar to the Android version:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class CountDownTimer {
  final Duration total;
  final Duration interval;

  final void Function(Duration) onTick;
  final void Function() onFinish;

  Timer? _periodicTimer;
  Timer? _completionTimer;

  CountDownTimer({
    required this.total,
    required this.interval,
    required this.onTick,
    required this.onFinish,
  });

  void start() {
    var endTime = DateTime.now().add(total);
    _periodicTimer = Timer.periodic(interval, (_) {
      var timeLeft = endTime.difference(DateTime.now());
      onTick(timeLeft);
    });
    _completionTimer = Timer(total, () {
      _periodicTimer!.cancel();
      onFinish();
    });
  }

  void cancel() {
    _periodicTimer?.cancel();
    _completionTimer?.cancel();
  }
}

void main() {
  var countDownTimer = CountDownTimer(
    total: const Duration(seconds: 30),
    interval: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    onTick: (timeLeft) {
      print(timeLeft);
    },
    onFinish: () {
      print('Done');
    },
  );
  countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Notable differences from the Android version:

- Uses a `Duration` instead of integers representing milliseconds.
- Takes `onTick` and `onFinish` callbacks instead of expecting you to extend the class with overrides.
- The `onTick` behavior might be slightly different with regard to the initial and final calls.  The [documentation for the Android version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) doesn't explain what that behavior is supposed to be, so I picked behavior that I personally think is reasonable.

Edit: Updated with a simpler implementation by maintaining two separate `Timer` objects.

Comment: Thanks, @jamesdlin for the input! So if I want to read any real-time sensor values within a time period, the code should be written within the onTick: (timeLeft) {
      
    }, right?

Comment: @Carl Yes, you'd replace that callback body with whatever code you want to execute periodically.